# rosout symbol lookup error

Tags: ros-melodic, rosout, tutorial, log4cxx, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI all,
I am introducing to ROS and I am trying to follow the beginner tutorials.
I've got an error when launching **roscore**:

```
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [13983]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311/
setting /run_id to 4de83cb2-83de-11ea-bdee-acfdce903724
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [13994]
started core service [/rosout]
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/rosout/rosout: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/melodic/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7log4cxx16AppenderSkeleton9setOptionERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_
[rosout-1] process has died [pid 13994, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/rosout/rosout __name:=rosout __log:=/home/albert/.ros/log/4de83cb2-83de-11ea-bdee-acfdce903724/rosout-1.log].
log file: /home/albert/.ros/log/4de83cb2-83de-11ea-bdee-acfdce903724/rosout-1*.log
[rosout-1] restarting process
```

It seems to be an error with some kind of symbol from **/opt/ros/melodic/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so** that causes an exit code 127 to **rosout**. It is repeating all the time the same error in new processes.

I have Melodic full desktop installation on Ubuntu 18.04. New installation clean and updated without any broken packages.

What do you think is it happening?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350127/rosout-symbol-lookup-error/) by [albert ciurana](https://answers.ros.org/users/53811/albert-ciurana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I found the problem.

It was a library mismatch due to **${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}** path order to find **liblog4cxx.so.10** library.

I had another software that uses its own liblog4cxx.so.10 and includes it from another path that was preeminent in order.
I found it executing:

> ldd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so

to see which libraries it is using, and I got that **liblog4cxx.so.10** was not the **/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cxx.so.10**.

The solution is to change the path order in **${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}**, or execute **roscore** as:

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH roscore

Problem solved.

---

Originally posted by [albert ciurana](https://answers.ros.org/users/53811/albert-ciurana/) with karma: 16 on 2020-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alexltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/54487/alexltz/) on 2020-05-06**:
Hello, thank you for your answer it helps me a lot. I got this error while I was trying to install bostondyn_healthcare package it might be the same issue for you?